# In Ruby, what is good way to filter all the methods of an object that contain the word "time" in it?

Tags: ruby, arrays, filter

I tried the following and it was partly working:

```
>> s.methods.map {|n| n if n =~ /time/}
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attri
butes", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, ni
l, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, ni
l, "timestamped_migrations", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "time_zone_aware
_attributes", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "default_timezone", nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, n
il, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, "recor
d_timestamps", nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,
nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

>> s.methods.each {|n| p n if n =~ /time/}
"skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes"
"timestamped_migrations"
"time_zone_aware_attributes"
"default_timezone"
"record_timestamps"
=> ["extended_by", "before_create", "vote_ids=", "save_without_dirty", "_delete"
, "touch", "daemonize", "after_destroy", "skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attribut
es", "methods", "send", "to_query", "becomes", "after_validation", "store_full_s
ti_class?", "save_with_transactions!", "autosave_associated_records_for_votes",
"require_library_or_gem", "enum_for", "taint", "instance_variable_defined?", "ac
     [...] and the rest of the whole array

>> s.methods.filter {|n| n =~ /time/}
NoMethodError: undefined method `filter' for #<Array:0x4de6b00>
        from (irb):93
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003121) is another easy way to accomplish this:

```
1.9.0 > require 'date'
 => true 
1.9.0 > x = Date.new
 => #<Date: -1/2,0,2299161> 
1.9.0 > x.methods.grep /time/
 => ["ctime", "asctime", "strftime"]
```

With the approaches you tried:

`map` applies the given block to each element of the given enumerable, returning a new enumerable.  That's not what you wanted here (as you saw).

`methods.each` sort of works, but obviously simply printing out the results isn't terribly useful.  It wouldn't be Ruby-like at all, but you could have done:

```
matching_methods = []
s.methods.each {|m| matching_methods << m if m =~ /time/}
```

to accumulate each method matching `/time/` into the `matching_methods` array.  Of course, if you're doing that, then

```
s.methods.select { |m| m =~ /time/ }
```

is preferable.

Lastly, `filter` doesn't exist in Ruby; that's what `select` (or `find_all`) is for.

Comment: ah i see, select and find_all are synonyms, and reject is the opposite.

Comment: @Jian: That's right.  When I first started using Ruby I always wanted to use `filter` too, but it didn't take long for `select` to catch on with me.  I think it helps to remember `reject` is the opposite of `select`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Enumerable.select](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003125)

```
 s.methods.select{|n| n=~/time/}
```

Or, use [grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003121)

```
s.methods.grep(/time/)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your approach with `compact`:

```
s.methods.map{|n| n if n =~ /time/}.compact
```